# Getting permission error in LightSwitch MVC

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, permissions, lightswitch-2013

I am using the LightSwitch server context in an MVC Controller. And my MVC code architecture in LightSwitch.Server project.

I am getting this error after hosting my project in Azure.

> The current user does not have permission to execute the 'Entity' operation.

Locally it's working fine. I am not sure why I am getting this issue in server.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but azure is experiencing some technical difficulties at the moment... https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#current

Comment: @MilenPavlov.. our other sites also deployed on azure its working fine. So do you think its azure issue?

Comment: According to Microsoft: "Services currently reporting impact include Web App, Operational Insights, Machine Learning, portal.azure.com and manage.windowsazure.com"

Comment: @MilenPavlov.. What about now? Azure status healthy now. Then also we are facing same issue :(